Matthew 21:31 is it about faith or deeds, or both?
Matthew 21:31 reads:

Whether of them twain did the will of his father? They say unto him,
The first. Jesus saith unto them, Verily I say unto you, That the
publicans and the harlots go into the kingdom of God before you.

Is the conversion here meant to convey that although their deeds in life seem like a "no!", these sinners actually believe in Jesus and therefore are saved?
Or is this about both faith and deeds, they believed and Jesus and stoped practicing sin? But then, why are they still called "publicans" and "harlots"?

Also quoting the preceding two verses would make this question much easier to understand.

This is very controversial text. For instance, the NLT has this footnote: "21:29-31 Other manuscripts read “The second.” In still other manuscripts the first son says “Yes” but does nothing, the second son says “No” but then repents and goes, and the answer to Jesus’ question is that the second son obeyed his father.".

@RayButterworth you're presuposing that because the second son "goes" that corresponds to works. But how do you know "to go" doesn't actually mean to believe, it's a parable after all. Consider Matthew Pole's commentary on Matthew 21:32:
"Others by their lives declare that they will not go; but yet upon second thoughts, having their hearts touched by the finger of God, they do God’s work."

We should consider the context of the verse in question:

28 “What is your opinion? A man had two sons. He came to the first and
said, ‘Son, go out and work in the vineyard today.’ 29 He said in
reply, ‘I will not,’ but afterwards he changed his mind and went. 30
The man came to the other son and gave the same order. He said in
reply, ‘Yes, sir,’ but did not go. 31 Which of the two did his
father’s will?” They answered, “The first.” Jesus said to them, “Amen,
I say to you, tax collectors and prostitutes are entering the kingdom
of God before you."

Here, it seems that Jesus refers to tax collectors and prostitutes being willing to repent and change their ways, while the religious leaders affirmed the Law but did not follow it. The religious leaders said "yes" but did not do as they should. The publicans and harlots originally said "no" but changed their minds and complied. Obviously the prostitutes would no longer work in that profession after they repented, while the publicans (such as Zacchaeus) could keep doing their work as long as they gave to the poor and did not conduct themselves corruptly.
Jesus then goes on to say:

When John came to you in the way of righteousness, you did not believe
him; but tax collectors and prostitutes did. Yet even when you saw
that, you did not later change your minds and believe him.

Conclusion: In context, Jesus taught that the reason for the publicans and prostitutes entering first is that many of them were willing to change their behavior, while the chief priests and elders often gave lip service to the Law but did not practice what they preached. They also failed to respond to John the Baptist's message, while many publicans and harlots did respond.

Our new spiritual life "in Christ" changes our positional standing with God upon having faith, even though we are still trapped in this carnal sinful body while living.  We are no longer viewed as the "harlots and publicans" that we are in the flesh.  We are now viewed as the "righteousness of God" in Christ by our spiritual renewing.
2 Corinthians 5:21

"For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him."

With keeping this positional change in mind (because of God's love and grace) it becomes easier for us to overcome the sin nature that we were all born into.
Romans 6:6

Knowing this, that our old man is crucified with him, that the body of sin might be destroyed, that henceforth we should not serve sin.

2 Corinthians 5:17

Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new.

Ephesians 4:22

That ye put off concerning the former conversation the old man, which is corrupt according to the deceitful lusts;

